# How to get actors and number of movies they played and number of movies they directed?

Tags: java, dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm struggling with writing code for Map and Reduce to later run on Hadoop. I have to get 3 columns:

1. Id of person,
2. number of movies he played,
3. number of movies he directed

Data file looks like:

- tconst (string)
  alphanumeric unique identifier of the title
- ordering (integer)
  a number to uniquely identify rows for a given titleId
- nconst (string)
  alphanumeric unique identifier of the name/person
- category (string)
  the category of job that person was in
- job (string)
  the specific job title if applicable, else '\N'
- characters (string)
  the name of the character played if applicable, else '\N'

[image: table]

And I have changed code a little from Wordcount.java of my previous exercise.

```
    public static class AvgSizeStationMapper extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

//        private Text year = new Text();
//        private IntWritable size = new IntWritable();
        private IntWritable size = new IntWritable();
        private Text category = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable offset, Text lineText, Context context)

                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                if (offset.get() == 0)
                    return;
                else {
                    String line = lineText.toString();
                    int i = 0;
                    for (String word : line
                            .split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")) {
                        if (i == 4) {
                            year.set(word.substring(word.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                                    word.lastIndexOf('/') + 5));
                        }
                        if (i == 5) {
                            size.set(Integer.parseInt(word));
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    context.write(year, size);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static class AvgSizeStationReducer extends
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {

        private DoubleWritable result = new DoubleWritable();
        Float average;
        Float count;
        int sum;


        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            average = 0f;
            count = 0f;
            sum = 0;

            Text sumText = new Text("average size of station for " + key
                    + " year is: ");

            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
                count += 1;
            }
            average = sum / count;
            result.set(average);
            context.write(sumText, result);
        }
     }
```

How can I do my mapper and reducer?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you couldnt use Hive or SparkSQL for such sturctured data?

Answer (score 0):

You're still doing a wordcount, so you should remove all the "averaging" logic in the reducer and just do a summation.

For the mapper, to get the "times an actor, `nconst` was seen"

```
// TODO: Parse the line
if (category.equals("actor")) {
    context.write(nconst, 1);
}
```

For "number of movies directed"

```
// TODO: Parse the line
if (category.equals("director")) {
    context.write(nconst, 1);
}
```

And these should probably be separate Mapper classes, but you can use the same Reducer because the logic would be the same

---

Alternatively, would be easier to just write a `COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY nconst` query in Hive

Comment: thank you, i can't use hive for now with this one but later i'll just try with it after ill get the java done